# Incorrect Email(without html) is sending through Mailgun

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine, mailgun

I am using Mailgun API based extension in Expression engine CMS When i disable the Mail-gun its sending perfect html mail but when I enable Mailgun its sending Email like in this manner:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_565e9f7740811
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

HELLO this is a message


--B_ALT_565e9f7740811
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>HELLO</b> this is a message

--B_ALT_565e9f7740811--
```

I type only once "HELLO this is a message" in this manner:

```
<b>HELLO</b> this is a message
```

But its showing two times in the email please resolve this issue.

Comment: @Abdulla you can download it from here https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php and if you want Email.php library you can find it in library section of codeigniter after downloading codeigniter from here https://www.codeigniter.com/download

Answer (score 0):

I had so much headache with sending though an API I ended up buying Escort (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort) and it simply worked perfectly and saved a lot of time making it worth it.  I use it with Mandrill, but it supports yours.

Hope this kind of answer is allowed, as I know it isn't directly solving your problem.